# How can I open a node.js inspect mode from inside Vim?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following node.js code:

```
console.log("one")
console.log("two") 
console.log("three")
console.log("four")
```

I know I can execute it as a node.js code from inside Vim by using the command `:%! node`... However, node.js has a [simple built-in debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_breakpoints) where I can debug my code very easily by using `node inspect file.js` on the command line. I'd like to do it from inside Vim though, is there any way of making Vim execute the file that I'm editing with this debugging option in a way that I still can control the debugger after using the command?

In my mind it'd be something like the following:

1. I open my js file with Vim
2. I use a command like `:%! node inspect` to open the debugger (this command is completely wrong, it's just an example)
3. In place of the file, I see now the interactive terminal from the debugger where I can type some commands like the following:

```
< Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/6d2eb151-92d0-4d70-b495-31148e202a77
< For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
< Debugger attached.
Break on start in file.js:1
> 1 console.log("one")
  2 console.log("two") 
  3 console.log("three")
debug> n
< one
break in file.js:2
  1 console.log("one")
> 2 console.log("two") 
  3 console.log("three")
  4 console.log("four")
debug> n
< two
break in file.js:3
  1 console.log("one")
  2 console.log("two") 
> 3 console.log("three")
  4 console.log("four")
  5 
debug> n
< three
break in file.js:4
  2 console.log("two") 
  3 console.log("three")
> 4 console.log("four")
  5 
debug> .exit
```

4. After exiting the debugger, I go back to editing my file

I'd like to do it from inside Vim without just typing the command on the terminal because I use [firenvim](https://github.com/glacambre/firenvim) to edit some files on the browser... Besides editing and executing them I want to debug them as well, everything from the browser... That's why I need to do it without typing the command from a terminal window. Is it possible? Can I use the command `node inspect file.js` inside Vim?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... If I use the command `:set makeprg=node\ inspect\ % | set autowrite | make` it'll do exactly as I described on my question: it opens an interactive terminal where I can do my debug stuff and after going out from it I'm back editing my file.

Besides that, once I enter this command I don't need to write everything again on the next time... Just typing `:make` does the job correctly.